# Why does .mhtml default app show up as Stable Chrome even though it opens Chrome Canary

Tags: google-chrome, file-association, google-chrome-canary

So I have this interesting... thing on my computer (idk what to call it).

I noticed, that an `.mhtml` file I downloaded had "Microsoft Edge MHT Document" as the file type description in explorer, so I looked into Settings and realized that I forgot to change the app for `.mhtml`. I wanted to change it to Chrome Canary as with all the other types, but the menu was different.

This is what shows up for all the other types (Chrome shows up as the Canary version):

[image]

(Edge doesn't have an icon because I uninstalled it)

But for `.mhtml`, Chrome shows up with the stable release channel icon, the name is just Google Chrome (not Canary) and Chrome Canary is not in the options:

[image]

The funny part: stable Chrome was never installed on this computer, I've always had just Chrome Canary since I bought the computer.

In explorer, the file icon is the stable Chrome logo:

[image]

When I double click it, Chrome Canary opens.

Stable Chrome is also in the "Open With" Menu.

It is not really a problem, it doesn't limit my user experience in any way and I can fix most of the problems by going to `HKCR\.html\OpenWithProgids`, copying the ChromeSSHTM.randomletters and pasting it into `HKCR\.mhtml\OpenWithProgids`.

I was just wondering how could this happen? How does my computer know of the existence of stable Chrome. Where did it get the icons from. Also about the icons... All the `DefaultIcon` values that I could find for `mhtml` were some IE icons. Where did it get the Chrome icon from?